# Surprisingly slow access of elements in TensorFlow/inefficient computation

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra

I am trying to optimise some linear algebra calculations in TensorFlow.

I have removed most of what I can from outside of the for loop. I am very surprised at how slow it is to access tensor elements though, see e.g. lines 118-120 and line 126.

Can someone explain to me why this is the case? And am I doing something computationally daft here? Thanks in advance

```
Timer unit: 1e-09 s

Total time: 0.228566 s
File: /var/folders/j4/t1rwqcnx7cn64bpmnmjyywkm0000gr/T/ipykernel_34080/3756757471.py
Function: vectorised at line 86

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    86                                           def vectorised(R, pos, ori):
    87                                           
    88         1       1000.0   1000.0      0.0      R = R
    89         1       1000.0   1000.0      0.0      Rm = pos
    90         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      Um = ori
    91                                           
    92         1       8000.0   8000.0      0.0      if Rm.ndim == 1:
    93                                                   Rm = tf.expand_dims(Rm, 0)
    94                                                   Um = tf.expand_dims(Um, 0)
    95                                           
    96         1      10000.0  10000.0      0.0      Nchans = Rm.shape[0]
    97         2      25000.0  12500.0      0.0      eps = tf.constant(
    98         1       1000.0   1000.0      0.0          1e-10, dtype=tf.float32
    99                                               )  # Small epsilon value to handle division by zero
   100                                           
   101         1      13000.0  13000.0      0.0      lf = np.zeros((Nchans, 3))
   102         1     462000.0 462000.0      0.2      tmp2 = tf.norm(R, ord="euclidean")  # Compute the Euclidean norm
   103                                           
   104                                               
   105         1     487000.0 487000.0      0.2      TMP1 = tf.norm(Rm, axis=1, keepdims=True)
   106         1    1113000.0    1e+06      0.5      TMP3 = tf.norm(Rm - R, axis=1, ord="euclidean", keepdims=True)
   107         1    1651000.0    2e+06      0.7      TMP4 = tf.tensordot(Rm, R, axes=1)
   108                                           
   109         1     365000.0 365000.0      0.2      TMP7 = (TMP1 * tmp2) ** 2 - TMP4**2  # cross(r,R)^2
   110         1      45000.0  45000.0      0.0      TMP3_cubed = TMP3**3
   111                                           
   112         1      34000.0  34000.0      0.0      TMP1TMP3 = TMP1 * TMP3
   113                                           
   114        95      87000.0    915.8      0.0      for i in range(Nchans):
   115        94   14177000.0 150819.1      6.2          r = Rm[i, :]  
   116        94   12267000.0 130500.0      5.4          u = Um[i, :]
   117                                           
   118        94   11876000.0 126340.4      5.2          tmp1 = TMP1[i, :]
   119        94   11094000.0 118021.3      4.9          tmp3 = TMP3[i, :]
   120        94   11060000.0 117659.6      4.8          tmp4 = TMP4[i]
   121                                                   
   122        94    3794000.0  40361.7      1.7          tmp5 = np.dot(r, r - R)
   123        94    2505000.0  26648.9      1.1          tmp6 = np.dot(R, r - R)
   124                                                  
   125                                           
   126        94   23033000.0 245031.9     10.1          tmp7 = TMP7[i][i]
   127        94   24124000.0 256638.3     10.6          alpha = 1.0 / (-tmp3 * (TMP1TMP3[i] + tmp5))
   128        94   18352000.0 195234.0      8.0          A = 1.0 / tmp3 - 2.0 * alpha * tmp2**2 - 1.0 / tmp1
   129                                           
   130        94    4851000.0  51606.4      2.1          B = 2.0 * alpha * tmp4
   131        94   17954000.0 191000.0      7.9          C = -tmp6 / TMP3_cubed[i]
   132                                           
   133        94    1867000.0  19861.7      0.8          if tmp7 < eps:
   134                                                       beta = 0.0
   135                                                   else:
   136        94   58565000.0 623031.9     25.6              beta = tf.tensordot(A * r + B * R + C * (r - R), u, axes=1) / tmp7
   137                                           
   138        94    8744000.0  93021.3      3.8          lf[i, :] = tf.linalg.cross(alpha * u + beta * r, R) * 1e-7
   139                                           
   140         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      return lf
```